# Cut out part of a vector drawable path

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

I have this xml vector drawable:

[image]

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <group>

    <clip-path
        android:pathData="M0,0h24v24h-24z"/>


    <path
        android:pathData="M12,22.806C17.968,22.806 22.806,17.968 22.806,12C22.806,6.032 17.968,1.194 12,1.194C6.032,1.194 1.194,6.032 1.194,12C1.194,17.968 6.032,22.806 12,22.806Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1.5"
        android:fillColor="#003087"
        android:strokeColor="#003087"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"/>

    <path
        android:pathData="M12,7.17V12L16.032,15.562"
        android:strokeWidth="1.5"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"/>

  </group>
</vector>
```

It looks how I want it to, however, I would like the clock hands to be transparent instead of white so you can see the background through the clock hands.

When I just set the #FFFFFF to #00FFFFFF the hands disappear but the whole circle is still visible. Is there a way to make the hands cut out the shape in the circle so the hands are transparent?

Comment: Which color should be the shape?

Comment: @blackapps the shape should be blue, as shown in the picture, i just want to cut out the clock arms

Comment: The shape of the arms i ment. How should it look like? The contour. Red?

Comment: @blackapps i don't want the shape of the arms to have a colour, i want them to be transparent